# How i can leave permanently enabled Django port 8080

Tags: django

I'd like to permanently enable Django to run on port 8080.

Right now I'm running Django with the command:
    `python manage.py runserver`

Now the question: how can I permanently enable Django?

blessings.

Comment: I have the same query. May be batch files can be used?

Comment: [Doesn't anybody read anymore?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/)

Comment: And this question got 2 upvotes? Whoaaa... where is this world coming to?

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a short cut to `./manage.py runserver <ipaddress>:8080`

Comment: And what makes this permanent? I think he means permanent as a service(e.g. nginx/apache)

Comment: And what makes this permanent? I think he means permanent as a service(e.g. nginx/apache) – rantanplan... hello, that's right, what is proposed super 9 is impossible unless you to open the port manually